# Найти количество символов в файле

Tags: cmd, bat

Требуется написать скрипт для нахождения количества символов в текстовом файле.
Основная идея примерно такая:

```
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%i in (%1) do(
    set string = %%i
    :loop
     if not (%string%)=="" (
         set /a char +=1
         set string = %string:~0,-1%
         goto loop
     )
 )
 echo Chars: %char%
```

Из-за разных ограничений в cmd этот скрипт не будет работать: то goto нельзя использовать внутри for, то скобки в if нельзя использовать из-за того, что он в for, и т.д. А вот как от всех них избавиться, я не могу понять.

Comment: Воспользуйтесь функционалом вызова внутренней процедуры бат-файла **call :strlen**. Пример процедуры подсчета длины строки в ссылке: [strlen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837418/how-do-you-get-the-string-length-in-a-batch-file)

Answer (score 1):

Можно вот так, если не заморачиваться

in:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set txt=long long text and more more more

:loop
for %%a in ("!txt:~%n%,1!") do (
    if not "%%~a"=="" ( 
        set /a n+=1
        goto :loop
    )
)
echo Chars: %n%
pause
ENDLOCAL
exit
```

out:

```
Chars: 33
Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно ещё примитивнее поступить :-)
Если мы знаем, что текстовый файл сформирован средствами Windows, то в нем для перевода строки используется 2 байта: CR+LF.
Считаем количество строк в файле и отнимаем их двойное количество от размера файла.

```
@set fname=%1
@for /f %%I in ("%fname%") do @set fsize=%%~zI
@for /f %%I in ('^(findstr.exe /n /r ".*" "%fname%" ^&@echo.:^) ^| find/c":"') do @set Lcount=%%I
@set /a count=%fsize% - ((%lcount%-1)*2)
@echo %count%
```

Comment: Понятно, что кодировка может оказаться Unicode. Поэтому приведенный пример - распространенный, но частный случай.